# Multiple WS calls in one Java Play action

Tags: java, json, web-services, scala, playframework-2.0

I am developing a Play 2 (v2.2.3) Java application (with Java 8) whose task is to fetch data from two web services and return a composed result.

From my first WS call I get a JSON array object with let's say job listings. Now for every job in this collection I want to call another WS which gives me something like the stock price of the company offering the job. After all this I expect my action to return this new 'enhanced' JSON array where along with each job listing I also see the stock price.

I started putting something together and I managed to get the list of jobs back but somehow the part where I glue the two call together is not working/being called.

```
public static Promise<Result> index() {
        final Promise<WS.Response> resultPromiseJobs = WS.url("https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?description=java").get();
        final Promise<Result> result = resultPromiseJobs.flatMap(response -> {
            JsonNode jobListings = response.asJson();
            // convert jobListings to a collection
            List<Job> jobs = ...
            // call map on this collection to fetch stock prices for each element
            jobs.stream().map(job -> {
               Promise<WS.Response> resultPromiseStock = WS.url("secondURL?someQuery=job").get()); // this also returns a promise
               // so let's map it to something
               // ??? what to map to and how to convert all this to a 'Result'
               resultPromiseStock.map();
               ...
            });
        });
        return result; // what is the correct object to return here?
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992400/multiple-ws-call-in-one-action-how-to-handle-promise-objects) is basically the same question but about Scala, I am interested in the Java solution

Comment: return the `resultPromise` that was flatmapped to a `Promise<Result>`

Comment: @LimbSoup: But then there would be a type mismatch: Promise<Result> and Promise<WS.Response>

Comment: Not `resultPromise`, the `Promise<Result>` that it was mapped **to**. i.e. `final Promise<Result> result = resultPromise.flatMap(...);`

Comment: Okay, now I get what you mean. But I still don't know how to collect all the `Promise`s from the inner map

Comment: Ah.. I see. You want to flatten something like `List<Promise<WS.Response>>` into `Promise<List<Something>>`. That depends on what you're doing with that list of WS results and how you want to handle errors (what if one fails?).

Comment: Correct. For each job request I map the `Promise<WS.Response>>` to a JSON key-value-pair and put it to the corresponding JSON job object. Unfortunately I am not well aware of what options do I have for handling errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56135/discussion-between-anton-and-limbsoup).

Answer (score 0):

From our chat I can see that you want to you want to map each `WS.Response` to a `JsonNode`, with will leave you with a `List<Promise<JsonNode>>`. [Promise.sequence](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/java/play/libs/F.Promise.html#sequence%28java.lang.Iterable%29) can be used to convert that `List<Promise<JsonNode>>` to a `Promise<List<JsonNode>>`, which you can then map to `Promise<Result>`.

```
public static Promise<Result> index() {
    final Promise<WS.Response> resultPromiseJobs = WS.url("https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?description=java").get();
    final Promise<Result> result = resultPromiseJobs.flatMap(response -> {
        JsonNode jobListings = response.asJson();

        List<Job> jobs = ...

        List<Promise<JsonNode>> jsonResultsPromise = jobs.stream().map(job -> {
           Promise<WS.Response> resultPromiseStock = WS.url("secondURL?someQuery=job").get()); // this also returns a promise
           // map this to the retrieved JsonNode
           resultPromiseStock.map(...);
        });

        // Convert the list of promises into a promise of lists
        Promise<List<JsonNode>> jsonResults = Promise.sequence(jsonResultsPromise);

        // Now map to Promise<Result>
        jsonResults.map(...);

    });
    return result;
}
```

The catch here though is that if one of the `Promise`s fails to complete, the entire list will fail. In many cases you might want this to happen if you need all the results. It's easy enough to discard failed `Promise`s from a list in Scala using this method, but I'm not sure how to do it in Java without `fold`.

Comment: `Promise.sequence` is what I also wanted to use but I get a compile error on this one. Besides that, shouldn't `jobs.stream().map` also have a return value?

Comment: The compile error was about the method signature and the arguments not matching. After a couple of tries I just converted the List<Promise<JsonNode>> to an array and all is fine. However the flatmap wants to see a return statement

Comment: I'm not completely familiar with the Java version of `flatMap`, but it should be returning the result of `jsonResults.map(..)` in some way.